# Cant add new area in Visual Studio 2013 / ASP.NET MVC 5.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-5.1

If I right click an MVC website project and choose Add->Area... then type in the area name and hit "Add". I get :

> "There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Value does
>   not fall within the expected range'"

All my colleagues also have the same issue.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Did you get any solution as i am also running into the same issue .

Comment: No, sorry I have not been able to solve this.

Answer (score 8):

I was stuck with the same issue and found a solution. It means your solution does not have web.config file.

Comment: This was appears to be the cause for me. I had deleted the web.config (complicated reason but it's to do with the type of app I was building). The web.config appears to contain nothing exciting but the fact that the web.config is missing seems to break something. Possibly a visual studio bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the area by using the Add -> New Scalfolded item option .

Hope it will help

Comment: I get exactly same result using this method. "There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Value does not fall within the expected range'"

Comment: It should not be as i am using it without any errors. Make sure you are using update 2 of vs2013  . You can check that from tool->extension and updates to verify the available updates.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @irfanMunir, but I'm not even seeing an option there? I'm on 2013 update 2. I even looked "online" through the dialog but couldn't find anything for adding an area to an MVC application. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out for anyone who comes across this thread... it's due to the fact that I'm in an MVC 3 project running VS 2013 Update 2. I get the option to add an area inside an MVC 5 project but not MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder name Areas right click you will see the option to create new Areas
More about issue here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-area-context-menu-option-is-missing-in-aspnet/859536